# Unable to receive correct data using i2c serial communication between two Arduino

Tags: arduino, i2c, master-slave

I'm using an i2c serial bus for communication between two Arduino (Uno = Master, Due = Slave) and I'm currently experiencing problems while reading data received by the slave.

The master sends some data using `Wire.write(command)`. The slave receives it and the handler function `receiveEvent(int howMany)` is called thanks the instruction `Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent)`.

Here is the simplified code for the serial communication:

#### Master's Sketch

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();        
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(8);
  byte command[] = {2, 5, 3};
  Wire.write(command, 3);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Serial.println("command sent...");
  delay(1000);
}
```

#### Slave's Sketch

```
#include <Wire.h>

int c = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Wire.begin(8);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
}

void receiveEvent(int howManyBytes){
  for(int iter=0; iter<howMany; iter++){
    c = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("c : ");
    Serial.println(c);
  }
}
```

#### Slave's Output

```
c : -1
c : -1
c : -1
```

It appears that three bytes are received but the data are not transmitted correctly. Any idea were there could be a mistake or a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you expect the data from the `Wire`, I think your slave should receive the data via `Wire.read()` instead of `Serial.read()`.

Comment: You are right, it solved the problem... I can't believe I didn't see this!! Thanks a lot!!